# MS Access - Counting Occurrences of a word in multiple columns

Tags: sql, graph, ms-access-2016

I have a database with a couple tables that tracks personnel errors that require rework by another person. Basically, a person on the job could rework up to 10 different work packages by other people throughout their shift. To make it easy, I just have columns in the table for rework_1/original_worker_1/rework_comment_1 (repeated up to 10) and the person who had to rework it. All of my worker's names are in a separate table so I can add people and my forms update dynamically with their names.  What I want to do is this:

1. Pull a person from my worker's name table.
2. Search for all occurrences of their name in another table in in column original_worker_X (where X is 1 - 10).
3. Output the values: Workers Name / How Many Times I found it in the original_worker_X columns.

From here I would need to make a bar graph so that each person's name had a bar with how many times someone had to rework something they did originally.

If I could do this with PHP and MySQL I would be in the money because I could brute force something with some PHP variables, queries, and loops but I am an access novice at best! I appreciate any help you wizards can provide.

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Expected Output Numbers:

[image]

Comment: Consider normalizing your wide table to long format that can scale beyond 10 workers. Storage will be more efficient and queries will be much easier. FYI: PHP can connect to Access databases.

Comment: I would love to be able to use PHP to do it, however, my "company"... ack.cough.ack... the government.... doesn't have an environment for me to work in/use.

Comment: I'm interested in the details of the long format concept. I'm a rookie database person in general. While I can do most things brute force, there is a lot of self taught issues I probably create on my own. Any references?

Answer (score 1):

so i will suggest you do the following

1. Create a new table,lets say table 3 with three fields
   A. ID, pkey, auto number
   B. original_worker, text field
   C. Person_doing_rework, text field
2. You will need ten insert statements that will insert each of the original worker 1-10, as well as person doing re-work , this is to a normalise table

Currently, the design of your table is a bit crude, and having a select statement with group by columns numbering 10 is not achievable

Below are samples of the insert statements
INSERT INTO Table3 (original_worker,Person_doing_rework)
SELECT original_worker1,Person_doing_rework
FROM table2 where isnotNull(original_worker1)

INSERT INTO Table3 (original_worker,Person_doing_rework)
SELECT original_worker2,Person_doing_rework
FROM table2 where isnotNull(original_worker2)

replicate this for  original_worker3 to original_worker10

Third step
You need a delete statement that will delete all from table 3, this is to ensure that the records from table 3 is not duplicated, since we don't have a pkey/fkey relationship between table 2 and 3

Fourth step
Place all the  queries into a macro in the following order
A. Delete query to run first
B. Insert queries to run next

Fifth step
Add a msgbox in the macro, that will run last, this is to inform you that all the other macro steps, i.e A and B above has successfully run.

Sixth step
You can now have a select statement from table 3 that can count the number of times an original workers' work is re worked upon, because you now have two main fields in table 3, one for original_work, and two for Person_reworked.

So any time you want to find out how many times some ones work has been re worked upon, you have to just click the macro button, this will run all the queries and put values you need in the table 3, after which you can view the details via the query in step 6.

SELECT original_worker, Count(Person_doing_rework),  FROM table3 GROUP BY original_worker;

Comment: This seems like a great work around. I suspect that a more clean way to do this would be to use a multi-part form that adds entered data into separate tables so its all done in real time vs. having to run a macro? Any good references I can read up on for that?